# Non-smooth Ito lemma for semi-martingales

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations, martingales

Is there an extension of Ito's Lemma where $X_t$ is a semi-martingale and $f:\mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function which is not smooth?

I've been looking but have not found much, any reference is appraciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are versions available for convex $f$ and for $f\in H^1$. Some places to start are  [On semimartingale decompositions of convex functions of semimartingales](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1255987418) (Carlen and Protter) and  [On Itô s formula for multidimensional Brownian motion](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FPL00008719)  (Follmer and Protter).

Answer (score 2):

Doeblin had nothing to do with this.
The extension of Ito formula to convex functions was derived by Hiroshi Tanaka and is called the Tanaka formula.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanaka%27s_formula

Answer (score 1):

The non-smooth generalization of Ito's Lemma is called the Ito-Doeblin formula.  Doeblin has a fascinating personal history.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfgang_Doeblin

Comment: Every, instance of Ito-Dublin I know requires the f_x to exist... can you post a link to a version where $f_x$ is rough?